# Cross derivatives of payoff functions in potential games

Tags: game-theory, potential-game

In [Monderer and Shapley (1996)](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~mansour/sem-game-02-03/monderer-potential-96.pdf) (pdf) there is the following theorem.

> The next theorem is well-known (and very useful).
>
> THEOREM 4.5
>
> Let $\Gamma$ be a game in which the strategy sets are intervals of
>   real numbers. Suppose the payoff functions are twice continuously
>   differentiable. Then $\Gamma$ is a potential game iff
>   $\frac{\partial^2{u^i}}{\partial{y^i}{y^j}}=\frac{\partial^2{u^j}}{\partial{y^i}{y^j}}$
>   for every $i,j \in \mathbb{N}$.

Where was this from? I might be missing something but I don't see a reference. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you asking for a proof or for the name of the theorem? "Well-known" is usually code for unclear origin.

Comment: I've seen more recent papers using this result by referring to this paper, but I can't find a proof or trace its origin.